# Подключение библиотек валидации

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть приложение на asp.net mvc. На layout page подключены библиотеки

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
```

У меня есть 2 частичных представления, одно вызывается ajax запросом, второе вызывается с помощью `@Html.Partial()` на первом. И вот мне необходимо что бы работали библиотеки валидации. Но если я в контроллере для ajax запроса первую view вызываю вот так вот `return PartialView();` тогда библиотеки не работают. А вот если я вызываю первую PartialView с помощью `return View();` тогда библиотеки работают, но не знаю правильное ли решение вызывать частичное представления с помощью `return View();`. Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше поступить? Если нужен пример моего кода, могу привести.

Это часть layout которая для вопроса необходима:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Контроллер:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult _AddAuto()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

Первое PartialView:

```
<div id="AddAuto" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Добавление нового автомобиля</h4>
            </div>
            @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "AddCarSuccess", OnFailure = "AddCarError" }))
            {
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("_CarAttributes")
                </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button id="btnConfirm" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Добавить</button>
            </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И в нём уже вызывается второе.

Вызов модального окна:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/Home/_AddAuto",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#modalWindow').html(result);
                            $('#AddAuto').modal('show');
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Да, нужен код, т.к. я не совсем уверен, но похоже вы пытаетесь подключить скрипты в partial, а mvc этого делать нельзя.

Comment: @AK добавил пример в вопрос.

Comment: @AK ну так что? Есть какие то комментарии по коду? Почему могут не подключится библиотеки?

Comment: @AK наверное ещё важная информация как я выкидываю partial view на основную страницу. Partial у меня это модальное окно, я получаю его ajax запросом и делаю show js'ом. Может эта информация тоже поможет.

Comment: @AK я кое что попробовал и мои догадки подтвердились. Если я напрямую вызову partialView с помощью `Html.Partial` на основной странице и вызову модальное окно вот таким вот способом `<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>` пример с сайта bootstrap, то библиотеки будут работать. Но у меня модальное окно выкидывается на страницу ajax запросом. А не сразу грузятся при запуске приложения. Пример моего кода привожу в конце вопроса. И поэтому на это окно не действуют библиотеки подключенные в layot. Осталось понять как задействовать их в моём случае.

Comment: Что мешает при старте вывести содержимое паршиал в div с `display:none` и сделать видимым, когда понадобится?

Comment: @AK а оно и так с display: none модальное окно делает это за меня. Просто я делаю это для того что бы каждый раз создавать модальное окно выкидывая его на форму, а в конце работы с ним я удаляю содержимое div'a modalWindow. Как бы сказать создаю и уничтожаю объект.

Comment: @AK в случае если просто открывать и закрывать, постоянно придётся на js чистить все поля, а тут просто создал и удалил модалку. И кстати я сейчас подумал ведь на модалке же работает jquery а он тоже в layout подключается, а валидация нет) Я даже пробовал её затащить в тот же бандл где подключается jquery но всё равно не работает, нечего подсказать не можете?

Answer (score 1):

Между `PartialView` и `View` есть разница. Вот уже дали ответ [в этой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662285/whats-the-difference-between-return-view-and-return-partialview).

- `return View()` - возвращает .aspx|.cshtml страницу, отрисовывает также нормальную страницу .aspx|.cshtml, которая может содержать один/несколько `PartialView`. Возвращает `ViewResult`.
- `return PartialView()` - возвращает .ascx|.cshtml компонент, часть html, которую можно запрашивать при помощи Ajax запроса, так и без него (Non-Ajax).
  Return `View()`. Возвращает `PartialViewResult`.

`ViewResult` как и `PartalViewResult` - оба наследуются от `ViewResultBase`.

```
public class PartialViewResult : ViewResultBase
{
   // Methods
   protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
   {
      ViewEngineResult result = base.ViewEngineCollection.FindPartialView(context, base.ViewName);
      if (result.View != null)
      {
         return result;
      }
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string str in result.SearchedLocations)
      {
         builder.AppendLine();
         builder.Append(str);
      }
      throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, MvcResources.Common_PartialViewNotFound, new object[] { base.ViewName, builder }));
   }
}


public class ViewResult : ViewResultBase
{
   // Fields
   private string _masterName;

   // Methods
   protected override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext context)
   {
      ViewEngineResult result = base.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(context, base.ViewName, this.MasterName);
      if (result.View != null)
      {
         return result;
      }
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string str in result.SearchedLocations)
      {
         builder.AppendLine();
         builder.Append(str);
      }
      throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, MvcResources.Common_ViewNotFound, new object[] { base.ViewName, builder }));
   }

   // Properties
   public string MasterName
   {
      get
      {
         return (this._masterName ?? string.Empty);
      }
      set
      {
         this._masterName = value;
      }
   }
}
```

Источник [@xandercoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2662320/6571020).

Comment: Намного полезней было бы вместо того, чтобы просто указать ссылку в ответе: а) дать свой ответ; б) самый лучший ответ (на ваше усмотрение) по ссылке -- перевести, опубликовать здесь и сослаться на источник ответа.

Comment: @0xdb согласен, поправил